# 2D GUI Shader for drawing lines on the screen

Tags: c++, shader, direct3d, hlsl

I'd like a 2D shader so that, for example, if the backbuffer is 800x600 I can draw lines, boxes, and so on in screen space.

I've got the code to draw the lines by bisecting them into triangles, that part all works fine.  My problem is what to do in the vertex shader.

Here's what I currently have, but nothing is appearing.  No errors or messages from the debug runtime.

```
VertexShaderOutput UILineVertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    output.Position = float4(input.Position, 1.0f);

    // Convert pixel coords to (-1, +1)

    output.Position.x = output.Position.x / videoWidth  * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    output.Position.y = output.Position.y / videoHeight * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    output.Position.z = 1.0f;
    output.Position.w = 1.0f;

    output.Color    = input.Color;  

    return output;
}
```

The videoWidth and videoHeight are set as constant buffers, in this case, set to 800 and 600.

I don't know if I have a subtle bug or a fundamental misunderstanding.  Thoughts?

Edit:

Here is the setup and draw call:

```
    V(g_UILineShader.SetShaderVariables());
    V(g_UILineShader.SetShaderConstants());

      auto pd3dImmediateContext = DXUTGetD3D11DeviceContext();

      pd3dImmediateContext->VSSetShader(_ptrVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
      pd3dImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &_ptrCBNeverChanges.GetInterfacePtr());
      pd3dImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &_ptrCBChangesEveryFrame.GetInterfacePtr());

      pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetShader(_ptrPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
      pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &_ptrCBChangesEveryFrame.GetInterfacePtr());

      ID3D11SamplerState * const * ppSamplers = { &_ptrSamplerLinear.GetInterfacePtr() };
      pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, ppSamplers);

      pd3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(_ptrLayout);

    // BUGBUG no doubt seriously inefficient to create a buffer each line draw!
size_t byteSize = vertices.size() * sizeof(UIVertex);
ID3D11Buffer * pBuffer = CreateVertexBuffer(pd3dDevice, byteSize, true, false, nullptr);
if (pBuffer)
{
    UINT stride = sizeof(UIVertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(NULL, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    pd3dImmediateContext->Draw(vertices.size(), 0);
    pBuffer->Release();
}
```

Comment: One thing I see in the graphics diagnostics is that an index buffer is still set from a previous draw call for a mesh (which worked).  The line draw code is NOT indexed, and I've called IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST), but the Index buffer is still being used.  How do I tell the device to "stop" using the index buffer from the last draw call?

Comment: Can you provide the code that includes the Draw() call?

Comment: I added as much of what I thought would be relevant for the draw setup and call

Comment: Did I overlooked it or did you forget to move your vertex data in your buffer? You create the buffer with nullptr as initial data and use it directly for drawing.